# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar el color del hover del option (select)?

Tags: html, css

Por defecto viene azul lo quiero cambiar a verde.

```
<select className='select' name="cars" id="cars">
  <option className='op'  value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option className='op'  value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option className='op'  value="volvo">Volvo</option>
</select>
```

En el css

```
option .op:hover {
  background:green
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Respuesta

De momento ese atributo no es personalizable.

### Ejemplo

Un ejemplo de lo que sí puedes hacer:

```css
select {
  background-color: yellow;
}

option {
  background-color: green;
}

option:checked {
  background-color: lime;
}
```

```html
<select className='select' name="cars" id="cars">
  <option className='op'  value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option className='op'  value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option className='op'  value="volvo">Volvo</option>
</select>
```